# How can i make a div and an anchor tag in one line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make the `div.logo` and `a.menu` in the same line.
how can I do it? I have tried a lot but not able to it. I have attached the code:

- edit:- i am trying to add transition when the `nav.items` comes down i tried this

```
    transition: height 3s;
```

but it didnt work

- how can i make the icon change to `X` when we click it i have the code for it i tried was

```
    menu.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
      </svg>'
```

but it again didn't work. I would appreciate if anyone would help :))

```js
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]
const navItem0 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[0]
const navItem1 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[1]
const navItem2 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[2]
const navItem3 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[3]

/*  
IMPORTANT!
let array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        array.push("navItem"+i)
        eval('navItem' + i + ' = ' + 'document' + '.' + 'getElementsByClassName' + "('nav-item')" + [i] + ';');
        console.log(navItem0)
}       
*/
menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navItem0.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem1.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem2.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem3.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  /*      menu.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
      </svg>' */
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%) !important;
  padding: 25px 35px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive-li {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .divider {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .nav-item {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    display: block;
  }
  li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <a class="menu">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="45" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
            </svg>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Note `<hr class="divider">` is not allowed as a child of a `ul`.

Comment: It's caused by `nav {flex-direction: column}`. Plus `.menu` has to bbe `inline-block` instead of `block`.

Comment: you can use ```flexbox``` for this learn about flexbox https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Do not just spam useless characters like dots in order to bypass the minimum required characters. Add actual usefull details and clarity. Like what you tried exactly!

Comment: Highly advice against using w3school. Its a poor site for learning as half of the content is outdated or bad practise. Use [this gudie](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead.

Comment: @tacoshy im sorry for that but it was showing code more text less and i had nothing more to write so sorry for that i wont repeat it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `logo` and `a` inside a container with class `logo-container` having below style.

```
.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* Align the logo and icon in same row */
  width: 100%; /* Setting full width */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Fill the space between logo and icon with blank space*/
}
```

This is needed only when the icon is visible. that is inside the media query `@media screen and (max-width: 890px)`

**Workiong Fiddle**

```js
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]
const navItem0 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[0]
const navItem1 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[1]
const navItem2 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[2]
const navItem3 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[3]

/*  
IMPORTANT!
let array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        array.push("navItem"+i)
        eval('navItem' + i + ' = ' + 'document' + '.' + 'getElementsByClassName' + "('nav-item')" + [i] + ';');
        console.log(navItem0)
}       
*/
menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navItem0.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem1.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem2.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem3.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  /*      menu.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
      </svg>' */
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%) !important;
  padding: 25px 35px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive-li {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .divider {
    display: none;
  }

  .logo {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }

  .nav-item {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu {
    display: block;
  }

  li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .logo-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; /* Align the logo and icon in same row */
    width: 100%; /* Setting full width */
    justify-content: space-between; /* Fill the space between logo and icon with blank space*/
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <a class="menu">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="45" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list"
        viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
          d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z" />
      </svg>
    </a>
</div>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i made a slight edit it would be great if you can help with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the logo text and menu  into a div

```
 <div class="header">
     <div class="logo">Logo</div>
     <a class="menu">
       <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="45" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
       <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
       </svg>
     </a>
 </div>
```

and add this style to that container div

```
.header{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0]
const navItem0 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[0]
const navItem1 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[1]
const navItem2 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[2]
const navItem3 = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-item')[3]

/*  
IMPORTANT!
let array = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        array.push("navItem"+i)
        eval('navItem' + i + ' = ' + 'document' + '.' + 'getElementsByClassName' + "('nav-item')" + [i] + ';');
        console.log(navItem0)
}       
*/
menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navItem0.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem1.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem2.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  navItem3.classList.toggle('responsive-li')
  /*      menu.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-x" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z"/>
      </svg>' */
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 16px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 6px 20px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 19%) !important;
  padding: 25px 35px;
}

.brand {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive-li {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 890px) {
  nav {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .divider {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .nav-item {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    display: block;
  }
  li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="brand">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <a class="menu">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="45" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
              </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <hr class="divider">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Try this.
The whole code is same. Only the `div.logo` and `a.menu` are enclosed in another `div` with a class of "brand".
Also, in the css, there is

```
.brand {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
}
```